# LDAP: How to get list of users from a specific group using C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

So I'm new to LDAP, and I'm having trouble finding a solid resource.

I'm able to make the connection, but I'm a little lost as to how to get a list of users from a specific group. Could someone help get me started getting a list of users from a specific group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about Active Directory as your LDAP store, and if you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // find the group in question
   GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

   // if found....
   if (group != null)
   {
      // iterate over members
      foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
      {
          Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
          // do whatever you need to do to those members
      }
   }
```

}

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Answer (score 1):

Library to be used for this: **System.DirectoryServices**

This code will get samaccountname and mail of all users in provided group-email and also from nested groups.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AD_LDAP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Group Email: ");
            string groupEmail = Console.ReadLine();
            List<ADUser> members = getGroupMembers.MembersInGroup(groupEmail);
            if (members != null && members.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Total Users: " + members.Count + Environment.NewLine);
                Console.WriteLine("*********************** Users in group ************************" + Environment.NewLine);
                Console.WriteLine("Users-Id" + "\t\t" + "Email Address" + Environment.NewLine);
                foreach (ADUser item in members)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.UserId + "\t\t\t" + item.EmailAddress);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (members == null)
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid group email!");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Group email has no members");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class ADUser
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    }

    class getGroupMembers
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// searchedGroups will contain all groups already searched, in order to
        /// prevent endless loops when there are circular structured in the groups.
        /// </summary>
        static Hashtable searchedGroups = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// "MembersInGroup" will return all users in the group passed in as a parameter
        /// The function will recursively search all nested groups.
        /// Remark: if there are multiple groups with the same name, this function will just use the first one it finds.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strGroupEmail">Email of the group, which the users should be retrieved from</param>
        /// <returns>ArrayList containing the emails of all users in this group and any nested groups</returns>
        static public List<ADUser> MembersInGroup(string strGroupEmail)
        {
            List<ADUser> groupMembers = null;
            searchedGroups = new Hashtable();

            // find group
            DirectorySearcher searchGroup = new DirectorySearcher("LDAP://DC=,DC=com");
            searchGroup.Filter = ("mail=" + strGroupEmail);
            SearchResult result = searchGroup.FindOne();
            if (result != null && Convert.ToString(result.Properties["objectclass"][1]) == "group")
            {
                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher("LDAP://DC=Your Domain Network,DC=com");
                search.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=group)(cn={0}))", Convert.ToString(result.Properties["samaccountname"][0]));
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
                SearchResult sru = null;
                try
                {
                    sru = search.FindOne();
                    DirectoryEntry group = sru.GetDirectoryEntry();
                    groupMembers = getUsersInGroup(group.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString());
                }
                catch { }
            }
            return groupMembers;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// getUsersInGroup will return all users in the group passed in as a parameter
        /// The function will recursively search all nested groups.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strGroupDN">"distinguishedName" of the group, which the users should be retrieved from</param>
        /// <returns>ArrayList containing the email of all users in this group and any nested groups</returns>
        private static List<ADUser> getUsersInGroup(string strGroupDN)
        {
            List<ADUser> groupMembers = new List<ADUser>();
            searchedGroups.Add(strGroupDN, strGroupDN);

            // find all users in this group
            DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher("LDAP://DC=Your Domain Network,DC=com");
            ds.Filter = String.Format("(&(memberOf={0})(objectClass=person))", strGroupDN);
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
            foreach (SearchResult sr in ds.FindAll())
            {
                if (sr.Properties["mail"].Count > 0)
                    groupMembers.Add(new ADUser { UserId = sr.Properties["samaccountname"][0].ToString(), EmailAddress = sr.Properties["mail"][0].ToString() });
            }

            // get nested groups
            ArrayList al = getNestedGroups(strGroupDN);
            foreach (object g in al)
            {
                if (!searchedGroups.ContainsKey(g)) // only if we haven't searched this group before - avoid endless loops
                {
                    // get members in nested group
                    List<ADUser> ml = getUsersInGroup(g as string);
                    // add them to result list
                    foreach (ADUser s in ml)
                    {
                        groupMembers.Add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
            return groupMembers;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// getNestedGroups will return an array with the "distinguishedName" of all groups contained
        /// in the group that was passed in as a parameter
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strGroupDN">"distinguishedName" of the group, which the nested groups should be retrieved from</param>
        /// <returns>ArrayList containing the "distinguishedName" of each group contained in the group apssed in asa parameter</returns>
        private static ArrayList getNestedGroups(string strGroupDN)
        {
            ArrayList groupMembers = new ArrayList();
            // find all nested groups in this group
            DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher("LDAP://DC=Your Domain Network,DC=com");
            ds.Filter = String.Format("(&(memberOf={0})(objectClass=group))", strGroupDN);
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
            foreach (SearchResult sr in ds.FindAll())
            {
                groupMembers.Add(sr.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString());
            }
            return groupMembers;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my code in this way to get the user details but I had an error 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll but was not handled in user code. I am just new to .net.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
            {
                // find the group in question
                GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

                // if found....
                if (group != null)
                {
                    // iterate over members
                    foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
                        // do whatever you need to do to those members
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```